# How can we implement the "time-limited free" feature in Android app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, time-limiting

My situation is, I have implemented an in-app billing product "remove ads" in my app for 0.99.

Now I wanna make it be free in a period of time for advertisement.

However, google play console not allow us to adjust product's price below 0.99.

So, after some survey, what I think is to implement this feature by a server.

I means, to check users' account by our server before calling google's in-app billing service.

Therefore my question is :

Above are what I think, but I'm not sure if there are other much better or easier solution about this issue? For example, maybe no need a server?

Or using a own server is the only way to implement the "time-limit free" feature?

Thanks you~!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- If you have your own server you can implement unique user and removes adds for some days
- If you are planning to charge monthly/annually you can implement **subscription** which have trial period implemented by google.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library that allows for this sort of behavior.
https://github.com/FutureHax/UberVerificationSystem